# How do I send stdout in real time from nodejs to angularjs?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, node.js

I have a script that runs for a long time. It generates an output. I am running this script from nodejs using child_process. How do I send the output of this script soon as it starts executing and do not wait for the script to complete. The code that I currently have waits for the script to complete and then outputs all the stdout at once on nodejs console.

Sample script:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Hello how are you " + str(i))
```

nodejs code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('python', ['path/test.py']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

console.log waits for the script to complete and then outputs

```
Hello how are you 1
Hello how are you 2
Hello how are you 3
Hello how are you 4
Hello how are you 5
```

in one shot. Is there anyway I can achieve sending stdout immediately as its written until the child process stops?

Comment: You *are* going to run into buffering issues here.

Comment: python output is beffered? try to `flash` it `import sys` and
`sys.stdout.flush()` after each `print`

Comment: It's not Python output that's buffered (*yes you can flush it*) but the OS will also buffer the output as well! Read: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering

Comment: I understand thats the difference between node's spawn and exec. Spawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is:

> You need to reopen `sys.stdout` in non-bufering mode.

**Example:**

```
import os
import sys

sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

So your program would look like this:

```
import os
import sys
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)

    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write("Hello how are you " + str(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me an insight on how I can send the response to frontend in the same fashion? every line, once outputted, do a res.send or res.write. It always waits for the script to complete and then sends the whole chunk. How can I do it realtime?

Comment: And you want this solution in what server technology using what framework? (*This is probably best asked as a separate question!*)